# Rails Model.select(attribute * attribute AS new_attribute) - new_attribute not in hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering if there was any way in rails to return a `new_attribute` in a select as statement in rails.

For simplified example `Books.select("'tuds' as new_attribute").first` where new_attribute isn't in the DB, just returns a bunch of empty active record objects.

Seems like this should work, but I'm not having any luck.  Any thoughts!?

Thanks!

-Mario
`

UPDATE: I'm a goof. I wasn't actually looking at the actual object and was just looking at the log in my console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me using Rails 3.2:

```
irb(main):001:0: User.select('full_name as whatever').first.whatever
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT id, full_name as whatever FROM `users` LIMIT 1
=> "Zap Brannigan"
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: It was.  I simply wasn't actually looking at the actual object and was just looking at the log in my console.